# Using multiprocessing pool with PyMongo cursor

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pymongo

I'm using a multiprocessing pool to perform a task on every document in a MongoDB collection. I've tried a few things and can only get it to work by using `pool.apply` in the following way:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient

def f(doc):
    print(f"[{os.getpid()}] {doc}"

db = MongoClient('connection_string')['database']
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    for doc in db.collection.find():
        pool.apply(f, (doc,))
```

And this will print every document to stdout. I then tried to use `pool.map` in a similar way:

```
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(f, db.collection.find())
```

But this immediately completed without printing anything to stdout. I expected this to work since `db.collection.find()` returns a `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` which is iterable. My next attempt was to make a generator that would `yield from db.collectoin.find()` in the following way:

```
def doc_gen(db):
    yield from db.collection.find()

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(f, doc_gen(db))
```

This didn't complete immediately, but was hung up as if it was trying to load the entire collection instead of lazily loading it like I would expect from `yield from`. I also tried setting `chunksize` in `pool.map` but received the same result of it hanging and not printing anything.

I also tried `pool.imap` with the generator and `db.collection.find()` as the iterator, but both would immediately complete.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about `pool.map`, or a way for me to get this to work? I think it's okay for me to use my first method with `pool.apply`, but am curious why nothing works with `pool.map`.